# Are there shops and places to train in Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, ravenloft, downtime, curse-of-strahd

Are there shops and places to train (as in PHB p187) in Curse of Strahd?

The town we're currently in at the very start (Barovia) of playing the module is completely deserted. I just want to know if everywhere in Curse of Strahd is like that. I'm open to spoilers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said you wanted spoilers, so...

For shopping:

> The town of Barovia is not deserted, people are just avoiding you. It contains at least one shop and dozens of occupants. However, prices at the shop are much higher than normal. Other towns also contain places to acquire goods and services, all with some amount of price inflation for at least some items.

For downtime training:

> Training is a bit tricky. You'll doubtless be able to find someone willing to teach you, but you'll have a much harder time finding the time to learn. You're in the land of the devil. He won't wait 200 days.

Comment: I will add this: this assumes your DM is strictly following the book. Curse of Strahd is a very free form module, and your DM may be doing something else entirely. Also...in addition to the Devil Strahd not waiting around for 200 days....the rest of your party may not want to go sit in some random town for 200 days while you learn to speak a new language. The published adventures aren't exactly designed with 'downtime' in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Page 43 of Curse of Strahd:

> Bildrath's Merchantile only has Adventuring Gear items under 25gp, but sells them at 10x their worth.